# check string matches from the given array of string in javascrpit

Tags: javascript, typescript

i trying  to  match my string with given array of string but this below code is not working,is  any suggestion might be help , below code is what i have tried

```
let myLongString = 'jkjdssfhhabf.pdf&awersds=oerefsf';
let matcherArray = ['.pdf', '.jpg'];

if (myLongString.match(matcherArray)) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

expected output is `true`. is there is any better solution is there to solve this type question thank you.

Comment: `String.match` accepts a regular expression as an argument, not an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to loop

```js
let myLongString = 'jkjdssfhhabf.pdf&awersds=oerefsf';
console.log(/\.(jpe?g|pdf)/i.test(myLongString));
```

Comment: (jpe?g|pdf) - just keep adding `jpe?g|pdf|png|gif` - the `jpe?g` handles either jpg or jpeg and the `i` makes it case insensitive

Comment: thx boss i marked your answer, you  have more than 85.700+ reputation how did you got this?

Comment: Answering thousands of questions during 8 years

Comment: 8 year means you are too old god and stackoverflow bless you boss , i also always increasing score by right inspect and edit the html then enjoying the reputation  and again do refresh

Comment: What do you mean “too old”? I’ve answered more than a million JS questions since 1997 or so

Comment: means you have more experienced person

Answer (score 3):

```
var Arrayvalue = ["a","b","c"];
var matchstring = "v";
if (Arrayvalue .indexOf(matchstring) > -1) {
  // if it is matches the array it comes to this condition
} else {
  // if it is matches the array it comes to this condition
}
```

The indexOf() method searches the your array for the specified item, and returns its position.

Comment: His string is inside a larger string

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.some` to iterate over the `matcherArray` with an `includes` test:

```js
let myLongString = 'jkjdssfhhabf.pdf&awersds=oerefsf';
let matcherArray = ['.pdf', '.jpg'];

if (matcherArray.some(str => myLongString.includes(str))) {
  console.log('match');
} else {
  console.log('no match');
}
```

Another option would be to turn the `matcherArray` into a regular expression, with each item separated by `|` (alternation):

```js
const myLongString = 'jkjdssfhhabf.pdf&awersds=oerefsf';
const matcherArray = ['.pdf', '.jpg'];
const escape = str => str.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&');
const re = new RegExp(
  matcherArray
    .map(escape)
    .join('|')
);

if (re.test(myLongString)) {
  console.log('match');
} else {
  console.log('no match');
}
```

Note that the `escape` function is there so as to *escape* characters with a special meaning inside a regular expression, such as `.` (matches *any character* by default, which isn't what you want here).

Comment: What a lot of work to arrive at something this does perfectly: `/\.(jpe?g|pdf)/i.test(myLongString)`

Comment: Of course you could manually write out a regex for some given `matcherArray`, but surely a *general* solution which can iterate over the `matcherArray` automatically, and either use a `.some` test or construct a regex, is far more preferable? Thus the few extra lines. Otherwise, if you use a hard-coded regex, you'll have to depend on `matcherArray` always being static. I would think that a general solution would be *better* than a narrow solution, not the other way around

Comment: I believe in pragmatic coding. There is no differences in maintenance between `[“....”,”....”] and` (...|....)` - so you want to add .png and .docx? No problem. You have 4 or more lines that need to be tested than I have